# How to run a buffer/region with shell commands as root user?

Tags: shell, shell-command

I need to copy-paste a bunch of shell commands to emacs and run them as `root`/`sudo`. How do I do it?

For instance, while configuring samba, I come across this instruction from the [documentation](https://man.archlinux.org/man/smb.conf.5):

> Become root:
>
> ```
>    mkdir /usr/local/samba/lib/usershares
>    chgrp foo /usr/local/samba/lib/usershares
>    chmod 1770 /usr/local/samba/lib/usershares
> ```

I would like to paste the commands to a scratch buffer and run. If they don't require `sudo`, then I can use `shell-command-on-region (M-|)`. But how do I execute these lines as root?

Prefixing `sudo` to lines fail with

> sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper.

Adding `-S` flag to `sudo` makes the command fail without asking for password.

---

As an another approch, I switched the `*scratch*` buffer to `shell-script-mode`, selected the region and `Execute region C-M-x`. This works great for non-sudo commands, but fails with the same message as above.

Comment: Forget about `shell-command-on-region`.  Read the docstring again and you'll understand it can't do what you want. You need to prepend `sudo` to each of the three commands, or start a session as root. You could run these on the scratch buffer, but that's not very orthodox. Try `M-x shell` instead.

Comment: "Prefixing sudo didn't work" - how did it fail?

Comment: @NickD It didn't work out of the box because `sudo` requires providing a password. Got this message: *sudo: a terminal is required to read the password; either use the -S option to read from standard input or configure an askpass helper*. I couldn't figure out where to give this `-S` option.

Comment: @aadcg `M-x shell` gives a more feature-full terminal. But pasting a block of text with multiple commands, especially when they need to be edited before being executed, is tricky. That's why I started with scratch buffer.

Comment: So paste them into a  buffer, fix them up as needed (the same thing you would do with a scratch buffer IOW), save the buffer into a file, and then execute it with `sudo bash /path/to/file` in a shell (in Emacs or in a terminal).

Comment: @NickD I'm trying to avoid creating the shell script. I see emacs has the culture of sending buffer/region to a running process, as in elisp evaluation. Trying to achieve something of that sort, to make executing bunch of one-time commands easy.

Comment: Yes, but sometimes reality intrudes: mixing sending directly with `sudo` does not work very well.

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to copy-paste a bunch of commands to emacs, edit them as needed, and run them all together. Please feel free to add if there's a simpler way to achieve the same result.

1. Paste the required shell commands to `*scratch*` buffer. Edit them as required.
2. Prefix `sudo -A` to lines that need to be executed as root.
3. Add `export SUDO_ASKPASS=/path/to/your/askpass/program` before the shell commands.

   - An askpass program is a helper that will prompt for passwords. On my kde system there is `ksshaskpass`, I could use `` `which ksshaskpass` `` above. It may be different on your system.
   - If `SUDO_ASKPASS` is already set in the environment, this line is not necessary.
4. Select the lines and `M-x sh-execute-region` (or `Sh-Script` menu -> `Execute region C-M-x`).
5. View the result on `*Shell Command Output*` buffer.